# Implement Value Filter lest then and greater than in 2sxc module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

How to implement Value filter in Query Designer for numbers like,
value is greater or less than number?

eg:

```
Value>10 and Value<30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now it's not implemented as part of the data-stream (status 2sxc 8.4).

It will be added some time in the near future, but could still be a few months off as there are so many other important things.

As of now, best use a bit of template level razor code (LINQ) to get it all going.